# Is it possible to disable lazy loading for ODM Doctrine?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine, odm

We are developing API with Silex and Doctrine (ODM) and we have object `Story`, which have property `images`.

```
class Story extends AbstractDocument
{
    /** @MongoDB\Id */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(
     *     targetDocument="MyNamespace\Documents\Image",
     *     storeAs="DBRef"
     * )
     */
    protected $images = [];

    // Other properties and methods
}
```

We have get method in repository (in AbstractRepository, from which extends all other repositories).

```
public function get(string $documentId) : array
{
    $document = $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->field('id')->equals($documentId)
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->getQuery()
        ->toArray();
}
```

This method returns embedded and referenced objects, but for `referenceMany` returns only ids without data.

Is it possible to deny lazy loading to get all documents ?

One possible solution, which we found - rewrite method `toArray`.

Comment: Sure.  You just add the objects you want to the select clause.  Plenty of examples.  I will admit I have not used the query builder with odm but I assume it will work.  And I'm not sure about the abstract stuff.

Comment: @Cerad Could you please provide an example, because I found on doctrine site

`ReferenceMany documents will always be handled as collections to allow for lazy loading, regardless of the strategy chosen.`

Comment: Wish I could but I don't actually have an ODM test case.  I would think that ->select('story','image') would do the trick but I don't actually know.  And you might need to explicitly join story and image.

Comment: @Cerad I'm using MongoDb, not SQL and I can't use `select` and `joins`

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use `->hydrate(false)` you are instructing ODM to get out of your way and return you raw data from MongoDB. You are seeing the `referenceMany` as an array of ids because that is the raw representation, no lazy loading is involved.

The cleanest way to solve your issue would be implementing `StoryRepository` which would fire an additional query to get referenced images:

```
public function get(string $documentId) : array
{
    $document = $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->field('id')->equals($documentId)
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->getQuery()
        ->toArray();
    $document['images'] = /* ... */;
    return $document;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this approach. Why I don't like it well, because I need write it for every repository (now I don't have a lot of it, but in future it's possible), which have ReferenceMany relations.

I thought that Doctrine provides solution for that.

Comment: Well it does out of the box with collections, but you're specifically telling it to not by requesting raw data.